# Notification Panel in Ubuntu Gnome Remix Crashed how to start without reboot

Tags: gnome, notification, notification-area

I was writing some python code which interacts with dbus to do notification which works great. not sure what happened, but somewhere along the way the notification panel at the bottom crashed.

I can't seem to figure out how to start it again.

Any idea what I can do to start it without rebooting?

Comment: As per the FAQ, questions about gnome-remix are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
gnome-panel --replace &
```

from a terminal will restart the panel without keyboard shortcuts or `kill` commands.